# Sending Litecoins to addresses in bulk

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, litecoin

I'd like to generate ~10,000 Litecoin addresses and send 0.0001 LTC to each one (for a giveaway), what would be the best way to go about automating it so I don't have to do it by hand? I know how to generate them, but what would be the best way to loop through them and make a transaction for each individual address? Is there a library I can use? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### To generate your wallets:

Go to this url:
https://walletgenerator.net/?currency=Litecoin

Move your mouse around to generate some randomness (or press the skip button on the right)
Go to the 'Bulk Wallet' tab

Enter 10,000 as the 'rows to generate'

This will generate your public/private keys. Be warned, I have never used this site, and do not trust it.

---

### To populate your wallets

Look into the wallet: https://electrum-ltc.org/
Here is a stackoverflow post about it: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/49790

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use https://walletgenerator.net/ to generate addresses if you know how to do it yourself. Just makes it a bit more secure. Also, if you are only going to put 0.0001 LTC in the account, it might not be useful as it will probably cost more to withdraw the LTC. Perhaps consider Ripple, as it has a very low transaction fee, so you could probably, for example, give away 1 Dollar worth of XRP and the client will be able to send it for 0.000012 XRP, meaning they'll still end up with most of their dollar.

As for bulk sending, you will need to compile the HEX instruction and then send that instruction to a live node. I don't have a live node, so I use blockdaemon. They have an api for submitting signed transactions. Here's the one for ETH:

```
https://ubiquity.api.blockdaemon.com/v2/ethereum/mainnet/tx/send
```

I would assume litecoin is probably simply:

```
https://ubiquity.api.blockdaemon.com/v2/litecoin/mainnet/tx/send
```

But I haven't tried it yet. I should be using the Litecoin endpoint soon. I am currently able to send XRP, ETH/ERC20 Tokens and BTC. I am now trying to finish off LTC and then the last one: BCH.

Check out XRP as it is much easier to work with. Receiving, sending, you name it. It should be the first coin anyone is introduced to, IMO, because it is so simple and fast.